# Exporting UFT 12 results into html throws the error “A reference to variable or parameter 'IDS_BC' cannot be resolved.”

Tags: vbscript, hp-uft

We have recently upgraded from QTP 11 to UFT 12.  The vbscript I used for QTP 11 worked great, but it is not running with UFT 12.  It says

> "A reference to variable or parameter 'IDS_BC' cannot be resolved.”

It says it might be undefined or out of scope. IDS_BC appears to be in the `PDetails.xsl` file for UFT, but I do not want to modify that file.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Here is the code:

```
Set xmlSource = CreateObject("MSXML.DOMDocument")
Set xmlXForm = CreateObject("MSXML.DOMDocument")

xmlSource.validateOnParse = True
xmlXForm.validateOnParse = True
xmlSource.async = False
xmlXForm.async = False

xmlSource.Load "\\cpsrv01\wwwroot\QA\QTPScripts\Curriculum_Pathways\TestResults\Server Actions\AppServers\Report\Results.xml"

If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    strErr = Err.Description & vbCrLf
    strErr = strErr & xmlSource.parseError.reason & " line: " & xmlSource.parseError.Line & " col: " & xmlSource.parseError.linepos & " text: " & xmlSource.parseError.srcText
    MsgBox strErr, vbCritical, "Error loading the XML"
End If

xmlXForm.Load "C:\Program Files (x86)\HP\Unified Functional Testing\dat\PDetails.xsl"

If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    strErr = Err.Description & vbCrLf
    strErr = strErr & xmlSource.parseError.reason & " line: " & xmlSource.parseError.Line & " col: " & xmlSource.parseError.linepos & " text: " & xmlSource.parseError.srcText
    MsgBox strErr, vbCritical, "Error loading the Transform"
End If

strResult = xmlSource.transformNode(xmlXForm)

If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    strErr = Err.Description & vbCrLf
    strErr = strErr & xmlSource.parseError.reason & " line: " & xmlSource.parseError.Line & " col: " & xmlSource.parseError.linepos & " text: " & xmlSource.parseError.srcText
    MsgBox strErr, vbCritical, "Error loading the Transform"
End If

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
strPath = "\\cpsrv01\wwwroot\QA\QTPScripts\Curriculum_Pathways\TestResults\Server Actions\AppServers\Report\TestResults_" & TimeStamp & ".html"
Set file = fso.opentextfile(strPath, ForWriting, True)
file.write strResult
Set file2 = fso.GetFile(strPath)
file2.copy ("\\cpsrv01\wwwroot\QA\QTPScripts\Curriculum_Pathways\AppServerResults\")
file.close
```

Here is the .xsl

```
<xsl:template match="Doc">
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="@type = 'BC'">  
        <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <tr><td class="iteration_head" bgcolor="gray"><xsl:copy-of select="$IDS_BC"/><xsl:value-of select="DName"/>
            <xsl:if test="@BCIter">(Iteration <xsl:value-of select="@BCIter"/>) </xsl:if>
            </td></tr>              
            <tr>
```

Comment: No one here can possibly know what you are talking about if you don't show your code.

Comment: Sorry about that...the code is shown now.

Comment: The VBS code seems to be ok on first glance. If the error is in the XSL file, it might be more useful to see that instead.

Comment: I have posted part of the xsl file.

Comment: The XSL file is not complete.

Comment: The entire file is pretty long...still want to see it?

Comment: Well... at least the line where `$IDS_BC` is declared? Watch out for `<xsl:param>` and also check any `<xsl:import>`/`<xsl:include>` lines. Maybe an import fails.

Comment: There are no '<xsl:param>', '<xsl:import>', or '<xsl:include>' statements in the code.  I also do not see where $IDS_BC is defined.  When I do a "find" on the page, it is only shown in the one spot above.

Comment: I see. Well, then you will need to define it. Maybe the old XSLT engine did not care about references to undefined variables. But this is clearly a bug. Either way, you will not be able to resolve this without touching the XSLT files. This looks like a tedious debugging job and those are not anything StackOverflow can help you with in an effective manner. Try to find out where the variable came from on the old system. Maybe just comment it out in the new system and see if that breaks anything you care about. In any case that's very likely not a question that can be answered here.

Comment: I actually used the pdetails.xsl file from QTP 11 and used it with UFT 12 and it worked fine.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Well, you solved it yourself. ;-) A final hint: I suggest you delete the question. This is such a specific, narrow topic that likely no one on the planet will ever have that problem again, so leaving the question online will not be helpful.